# How to breakdown wax, preferably beeswax

Tags: organic-chemistry

I have a project that I'm working on at the moment, but I'm stuck on this detail. I'd like to find out what can I supplement beeswax with that is organic, non toxic, and safe if accidentally consumed, in order to speed up decomposition rate of beeswax to a time frame of about 1-6months. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know beeswax does not decompose. If you just want to melt it, use heat. If you want to break it down using a solvent, try [turpentine](http://www.beesource.com/forums/showthread.php?222805-Solvent-for-wax-removal) (paint thinner).

Comment: So there's really no non toxic solvent to use?

Answer (score 0):

I would try [d-limonene](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limonene) or maybe perflubron if you can find it. Both are non polar non toxic solvents so they should work. Another thing that I have heard might work is vegetable oil or most other oils you can find in your kitchen. But otherwise d-limonene is the best bet because it's organic, nontoxic, and safe to consume.